# subquery case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
SELECT   Case 
           when  V.[Code Article] in 
              (SELECT   [Code Article]
              FROM     [Prix Revient MPX CMR]  c
              WHERE    CONVERT(DATE, V.[Date Time]) =  [DATE] and [CMR] = V.[Code Site] )
              then c.[Prix de revient réel] 
          ELSE     V.[Prix de Revient]  
        end as [Prix de Revient]
FROM     dbo.[Sales] V
```

I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "c.Prix de revient réel" can not be bound

How to modify it ?

Comment: And to save every anglophile the job of translating; `The multi-part identifier " c.Prix de revient réel" can not be bound.`

Comment: The c.[Prix de revient réel] isn't available outside the sub-query,

Comment: It would help answer this to give some details of your table structure, a sample of the data, and the expected result.

Comment: If you want to select the column `Prix de revient réel` of the table that you use a s lookup table for the `Code Article` you have to use a sub-query or join. Othwerwise it's not visible in the main query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you formatted the query like this:

```
SELECT (Case when V.[Code Article] in (SELECT c.[Code Article]
                                       FROM [Prix Revient MPX CMR]  c
                                       WHERE CONVERT(DATE, V.[Date Time]) =  c.[DATE] and c.[CMR] = V.[Code Site]
                                     )
             then c.[Prix de revient réel] 
             ELSE V.[Prix de Revient]  
        end) as [Prix de Revient]
FROM  dbo.[Sales] V;
```

Then the problem would be obvious.  There is no `c` for the `then` clause.  Presumably you want a `join`:

```
select coalesce(c.[Prix de revient réel], V.[Prix de Revient]) as [Prix de Revient]
from dbo.[Sales] V left join
     [Prix Revient MPX CMR]  c
     on CONVERT(DATE, V.[Date Time]) =  c.[DATE] and
        c.[CMR] = V.[Code Site] and
        V.[Code Article] = c.[Code Article]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `sub-query` or `join`

Try below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  V.[Code Article] IN (SELECT [Code Article] 
                                       FROM [Prix Revient MPX CMR]  c
                                       WHERE CONVERT(DATE, V.[Date Time]) =  [DATE] and [CMR] = V.[Code Site] 
                                       )
            THEN (SELECT [Prix de revient réel] FROM [Prix Revient MPX CMR] WHERE CONVERT(DATE, V.[Date Time]) =  [DATE] and [CMR] = V.[Code Site])
        ELSE     V.[Prix de Revient]  
        END AS [Prix de Revient]
FROM dbo.[Sales] V
```